# How to set Amazon S3 Bucket default image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on S3 with some public images in it. If I browse to the folder without specifying a file name, it serves me an image.

So using a link like this, I am still getting an image back.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/folder_name/

The image served is one of mine that I've obviously uploaded at some point in the past but I don't recall ever setting it as a folder default. Is there an option somewhere to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `/bucket_name/folder_name/` is the object path. In S3, there really is not a true concept of folders. `/` in an object path, can be displayed as folders, but they are still just part of the key in the end.

Comment: I've tried to add a default image in the bucket with the same name as the folder, with no success. Is this what you meant?